# output of generated tests peach fuzzer to the executable file

Tags: xml, fuzzing, fuzzer, peach

Peach Fuzzer.
I need to pass the generated tests to the executable file as an argument. This can be configured in the xml file that is called the "peach pit".
For example, here is a test record in text files

```
<Test name="Default">
  <StateModel ref="State"/>
    <Publisher class="FilePerIteration">
      <Param name="FileName" value="tests1/tes_{0}.txt"/>
    </Publisher>
</Test>
```

Here is an example of outputting tests to the console

```
<DataModel name="Data">
   <!-- ... -->
</DataModel>
<StateModel name="TheState">
  <State name="initial">
    <Action type="output">
      <DataModel ref="Data" />
    </Action>
  </State>
</StateModel>
<Test name="Default">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Publisher class="Console" />
</Test>
```